# Searching all connected signals to PyQt4 object

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

Is there a way to easily determine what slots are connected to a signal or object in PyQt4?
The main use-case for this is connecting all default slots for a given object.  For example, maybe I want to enable sorting on a `QTableView` with `setSortingEnabled()` but I want to control the `horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorChanged` signal myself.  I need to see what all slots are connected to the `sortIndicatorChanged` signal and disconnect them.

Ideally I'd like a function like the following:

```
def print_all_connected(qobject, signal=None):
    signals = qobject.signals() if signal is None: else [signal]
    for signal in qobject.signals():
        for slot in qobject.connectedSlots():
            print slot
```

So a call like `print_all_connected(my_table_model, 'dataChanged')` would print all the slots connected to the `dataChanged` signal on the `my_table_model` slot.

I think standard Qt interprets a call to `disconnect()` as an automatic disconnection of all slots for the signal it was called on.  Unfortunately, I don't think PyQt4 implements this, signals must be disconnected one by one.  However, I'd still like to be able to search an object and see what slots or signals it has and print/disconnect them, etc.

In addition, I know there is a `QObject.receviers()` method that can return the number of 'receivers' connected to a given slot.  However, this doesn't tell me who/what those receivers are.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect works just like in Qt. See the [documentation for disconnect in pyQt](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html?highlight=disconnect#disconnect).

I couldn't find a way to do what you want, but you can check the doku for:

1. [New-style Signal and Slot Support](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)
2. [Old-style Signal and Slot Support](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html)
3. [Things to be Aware Of](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/gotchas.html)

Comment: You are right.  The `disconnect()` call does work for as it does in Qt.  I could have sworn I read somewhere this was not the case, but the PyQt4 documentation you referenced in #1 clearly states I was wrong.